# Usar objeto tipo clase desde GUI,

Tags: c++, qt

estoy creando un programa muy simple con C++, usando el IDE QT creator y me surge una duda

tengo una clase Persona, con dos atributos

```
#ifndef PERSONA_H
#define PERSONA_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Persona
{
public:
    Persona();

    string nombre;
    int edad ;

};

#endif // PERSONA_H
```

En el main cree un objeto tipo Persona llamado persona1 :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "Persona.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();


     Persona persona1;

      persona1.edad = 20;
      persona1.nombre = "Maria";


    return a.exec();
}
```

Cree en mi interface grafica un boton y un label. Quiero que al dar clic en el boton, el texto del label cambie a persona1.nombre, pero estoy teniendo problemas de visibilidad, y la clase Mainwindows no ve el objeto persona1 , creado en Main,
mi pregunta es > como hacer que Mainwindows vea los objetos tipo x creado en main.cpp

codigo de MainWindows

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText(persona1.edad);  //varios errores
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente, tienes problemas de visibilidad. Para que `mainWindow` pueda usar `persona1` tiene que tener, de alguna forma, acceso a dicho objeto.

Hay varias soluciones a este problema pero para un caso tan simple yo iria a lo facil: Basta con crear una función que permita pasar a `MainWindow` una copia de `persona1`.

```
#include "persona.h"

class MainWindow : QMainWindow
{
  Persona persona;

public:

  void SetPersona(Persona p)
  { persona = p; }

private slots:

  void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
  {
    ui->label->setText(persona.edad);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Persona persona1;

  persona1.edad = 20;
  persona1.nombre = "Maria";

  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.SetPersona(persona1);
  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```